# Difficulty in getting value out of if -else loop in python-tkinter

Tags: python, if-statement, tkinter

I am new to Python programming. I want to display a number based on the input code. The below code shows four irrespective of the entered code.

```
from Tkinter import*
from math import*
root = Tk()
root.title('Barcode Reader') #title of code
text1 = StringVar() #initiate text1
text1.set('0') #initiate text1
entry=Entry(root) #entry widget
entry.pack()
def check():
    if entry.get() == 0011: # entered code
       print(entry.get())
       text1.set('2') # corresponding value for 0011
    elif entry.get() == 0100:
       text1.set('3') # corresponding value for 0100
    else:
       text1.set('4') 
button=Button(root, text='check', command=check) #button definition
button.pack()
label=Label(root, textvariable=text1) #label to display result
label.pack()
mainloop()
```

Comment: hint: `entry.get()` always returns a string, and you are trying to compare it to a number.

Comment: As others have mentioned, simply replace `0011` and `0100` with `"0011"` and `"0100"` to compare them as strings.

Comment: Dear Bryan & Nae, Thanks for your reply and clarifications. Now the code works.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code shows `4` is that `entry.get()` returns a `str`, yet you are comparing it to the `int` `11`. Also it appears as though there is no use for `from math import *`. Furthermore it is a bad habit to use `from Tkinter import *`, instead consider using `import Tkinter as Tk`, which results in a less cluttered namespace.